# how to delete a substring and get another part from that string

Tags: iphone, nsstring, substring

I have some string that have a type like this

```
NSString *string1 = @"/Users/mine/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.2/Applications/02221798-1B7A-46B4-928F-F5BE37E177B5/Documents/Project/Project 1/Folder 1/2.php";
```

if i just want to get the "02221798-1B7A-46B4-928F-F5BE37E177B5"

i have implement a code like this :

```
NSString *subString1;
int count = [string1 length];
NSLog(@"count : %d", count);
subString1 = [string1 substringFromIndex:121];
```

but it left "02221798-1B7A-46B4-928F-F5BE37E177B5/Documents/Project/Project 1/Folder 1/2.php"

how can i do to fix it??

Comment: You'd want to search for somekind of "split" method, you then split depending on the '/' in that string and get an array that you can easily access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the name of your app's parent directory you should try this instead:

```
NSString *appUUID = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] lastPathComponent];
```

This will work both on a device and Simulator.

If you need to get the full path to the Documents folder inside your app sandbox:

```
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
```

If you need to append a path component to a path string:

```
NSString *projectPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Project"];
```

Please, take a look at NSString documentation, section "Tasks", ["Working with Paths"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW38). It is a must-read.

Comment: can you give me more example?

Comment: The above code returns your app's parent directory name, something like app UUID. First, it gets the full path to the app bundle, then deletes the app name and extension, then returns the last path component, which happens to be the name of the directory your app is in. Did you mean to ask something different?

Comment: thx for your help...but if i want to get the "Project 1", can u give me another help?

Comment: I edited my answer with more examples and a link to docs, it was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use stringWithRange method of NSString.
subString1 = [string1 stringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startPos,yourLengthToSelect)];

or you can use componentSeparetedByString and break string using @"/". it will return array of string. get your desired string using array index.

Comment: NSString has a special method, `-pathComponents`, to get the array of path components. You should *always* use it working with paths, rather than `-componentsSeparatedByString:`, because "/" is considered an internal implementation detail of the underlying file system.